# Video Size is large while quality is poor

Tags: video

I've got some old movies in different format, the problem is the quality of the video is not that good but it's taking a huge space about 1.5GB, is there any software that can reduce the size of the video automatically while preserving the quality.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using ffmpeg. I am quoting the following [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/4244/how-do-i-reduce-the-size-of-a-huge-mp4-video/4252#4252) for a similar question

> You can try using something such as ffmpeg or mencoder to reencode it
>   with a lower bitrate, e.g.:
>
> Calculate the bitrate you need by dividing 1 GB by the video length in
>   seconds. So, for a video of length 16:40 (1000 seconds), use a bitrate
>   of 1000000 bytes/sec:
>
> `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -b 1000000 output.mp4`
>
> Additional options that might be worth considering is setting the Constant Rate Factor, which
>   lowers the average bit rate, but retains better quality. Vary the CRF
>   between around 18 and 24 — the lower, the higher the bitrate.
>
> `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -crf 20 output.mp4`